# LTSPICE Logic Buffer: What does the extra pin do?

Tags: simulation, ltspice

I give up... what is the extra pin for?

[image]

LTSpice Documentation is horrible....

[image]

Comment: Hm. You have nice answers but horrible questions... What is this? Which documentation? I understand that it is a Schmidt trigger inverting buffer, but.. come on. I would guess it's a tri-state control without any more information.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Sorry,, it's just a plain old Schmitt inverter from the digital catalog. All those digital parts seem to have an extra pin or two. It does not seem to do much.

Comment: Is it linked to a physical part?

Comment: Nope just your generic logic.

Comment: It's ground. More letters to fill out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As described in the help under LTspice → Circuit Elements → Special Functions (near the bottom), it is the "common" pin, a.k.a. "node 8".

If you leave it unconnected, it is automatically tied to the global node 0 (ground).

Comment: Thank's Dave. I'm fairly new to LTSpice so am having a hard time with UI...

Comment: @Trevor Still, he gave you the answer from the manual, the one you say it's horrible (and post a screenshot of the component's selection list, which doesn't give help about the parts. What I'm trying to say is it would be better and more reasonable to not blame the tools, first.